# Can't access folders anymore: Input output error

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, dual-boot, ntfs

I was using my pc and downloading some stuff from the internet and all of a sudden one of the folders `MIT6.046JS05` got removed. I couldn't see it in Nautilus anymore. I tried `ls` with command line and it says:

```
ls: cannot access 'MIT6.046JS05': Input/output error
cs61b  info  MIT6.046JS05  MIT6.851S12  MIT6.851S12_archive.torrent  MIT8.02S02
$ ls -ah
ls: cannot access 'MIT6.046JS05': Input/output error
.  ..  cs61b  info  MIT6.046JS05  MIT6.851S12  MIT6.851S12_archive.torrent  MIT8.02S02
```

The drive is NTFS and I have been using `ntfsfix` to get rid of the errors while mounting. I have dual booted with Windows 10 and I noticed it first from Windows. There must have been some conflicts and led to this issue. I can see the folder from Ubuntu command line, but can't access it. How do I fix this? Or how do I at least recover the files?

Comment: See [Recovering broken or deleted NTFS partitions](http://askubuntu.com/a/776317/271).

Comment: Also, possibly related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306263/using-ddrescue-to-retrieve-data-off-a-failing-ntfs-disk/