# How to ensure that an NTFS disk image file is not being written to when mounted?

Tags: mount, ntfs, readonly, disk-image

I have a 500GB raw disk image file on my HDD that I’ve called `dysk.img` and that is a result of `dd`'ing the contents of an external single NTFS partion drive. Its purpose is to attempt data recovery with the `ntfsundelete` program (and the results of the initial scan are promising).

Before that, however, I’d like to examine its current, not deleted content. Thus I’d like to mount it. For obvious reasons, I want to ensure that mounting this file will not result in a single bit being written to it.

`mount --read-only` doesn’t seem to be the solution, sadly. Because, according to `man mount`:

> Note that, depending on the filesystem type, state and kernel behavior, the system may still write to the device.  For example, ext3  and  ext4  will replay  the  journal  if  the  filesystem  is dirty.  To prevent this kind of write access, you may want to mount an ext3 or ext4 filesystem with the ro,noload mount options or set the block device itself to read-only mode, see the blockdev(8) command.

Can the above apply to NTFS as well? Sadly `mount` doesn’t support the `noload` option…

Unfortunately, I had carelessly written some files with Windows-incompatible names (containing the `?` character for instance), and this had made Windows mark this filesystem for scheduled check – thus, I’m getting constant warnings from `ntfsundelete` now and cannot run `ntfsundelete` without the `--force` option. Can this further increase the risk of some accidental writes?

As of now, only root has write access to this file. I’m not sure if this is enough, as IIUC there’s always some rights elevation when mounting.

Would making `root` the owner of this file and denying anyone, even the owner, write access be helpful?

Would it be helpful to attempt to use the `blockdev` command suggested by `man mount` to this file? Or would it be risky or harmful to issue `blockdev --setro` to an image file, as opposed to an actual device?

Comment: You could always `chattr +i` the image file. :) Now, allow me to make a small self-promotion... my open source software called RecuperaBit reconstructs NTFS and it doesn't write *anything* on the image file.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto Thank you, it really helped me! You really should convert this comment to an answer, so I can upvote and accept it. BTW, if I can suggest something, it would be convenient if you’d allow writing the tree directory structure to a file.

Comment: Good! But which one of my remarks helped you precisely? The one about chattr or the one about RecuperaBit? Please add suggestions to the issue tracker on GitHub. :)

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto Well, your RecuperaBit managed to recover most of the important data that had been lost :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of the answer you are looking for is given in the quote you've cited:

> set the block device itself to read-only mode

In your case, that's a simple file. So you can:

```
chmod a-w disk.img
```

Not even the owner needs to write to it.

> Would making `root` the owner of this file and denying anyone, even the owner, write access be helpful?

Basically, **yes,** but remember that `root` can bypass most permission "limitations". So you should run your data recovery program as a user different from `root`.

If you want to mount the file, you cannot simply do that. However, if the image file is saved inside a file system that support `chattr` (basically EXT4 and other common Linux file systems) **you can make the file immutable:**

```
chattr +i disk.img
```

Now not even `root` can do anything to it. It cannot be written or deleted. Use `chattr -i` to revert the flag after you are done.

## Alternative approach

If you want to extract data from a (possibly damaged) NTFS drive, you might want to consider using [RecuperaBit](https://github.com/Lazza/RecuperaBit), which is a software I developed to perform file system reconstruction. Currently it only supports NTFS, but it has a couple of advantages:

- It doesn't write anything on the image file. Simply put, *it doesn't support writing* on a drive, because it's oriented to digital forensics. Hence you don't risk doing it accidentally.
- It can read the directory tree even if it's broken. You will get the most accurate depiction of each partition, at least from the metadata that is available.

I have discussed its usage in the following answers:

- [Copying file to block device](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/283009/84179)
- [Using ddrescue to retrieve data off a failing ntfs disk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/309897/84179)